# Can I substitute variables in JUnit failure reasons?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

In log4j I can do this:

```
logger.debug("Logging in user {} with birthday {}", user.getName(), user.getBirthdayCalendar());
```

Can I do something like this in JUnit failure reasons?

```
assertTrue("Got {}, but expected {}", StringUtils.equals(bmf.toString(), finalMessage));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hamcrest marchers are what you need here.

```
assertThat(bmf.toString(), is(finalMessage));
```

This will print out failure messages like

```
Expected "apples" but got "oranges".
```

---

**Edit**

The power of Hamcrest style matchers comes from the ability to write your own.

For instance, in your test class, you could add a method:

```
private Matcher<BMF> stringsTo(final String desired) {
    return new TypeSafeMatcher<BMF>() {
        protected boolean matchesSafely(BMF item) {
            return item.toString().equals(desired);
        }

        public void describeTo(Description description) {
            description.appendText("should stringify as ").appendValue(desired);
        }

        protected describeMismatchSafely(BMF item, Description description) {
             description.appendText(" was ").appendValue(item.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

You could then use this in your test method:

```
@Test
public void myTest() {
    assertThat(bmf, stringsTo(finalMessage));
}
```

You are not testing that the bmf object equals a string; you are testing that the bmf is of class `BMF`, is non-null, and when `toString()` is called on it, it produces `finalMessage`.  You could make the test as complex as needed, and the descriptions as descriptive as desired.

Comment: this seems irrelevant. all the OP has to do is use assertEquals instead of assertTrue, no hamcrest required.

Comment: @NathanHughes:  I agree with you to an extent, but having slightly better messages about *why* it wasn't equivalent is actually hugely beneficial.

Comment: @NathanHughes Oddly, I've used Hamcrest so much, I forgot that assertEquals even existed!

Comment: The power of Hamcrest matchers comes from the ability to write your own, which can consume the arguments being tested and construct your own custom failure message from the arguments.

Comment: @AJNeufeld: that would be a cool thing to add here. also if the OP just wants to specify args after the format string, there's always String.format